# Why use multiple node handles?

Tags: ros, camera, multiple, node, pointgrey

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am currently developing a ROS packages to to PointGrey Grasshopper3 and I've seen that some packages like the  camera1394 use more than one node handler. Does anyone know why?

Thanks,

Pedro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185308/why-use-multiple-node-handles?/) by [PedroGusmao](https://answers.ros.org/users/7556/pedrogusmao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2014-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See: http://answers.ros.org/question/32061/what-are-the-deferences-between-getnodehandle-and-getprivatenodehandle-in-nodelet/

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0